# Syntax for getting attributes of entries created via accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` model that looks something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :event_sessions, through: :events

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
end
```

I have a form that submits a `User`, `Event`, and `EventSession` to my `UserController` and everything works as expected.

Once my controller performs a `@user.save`. I want pull out the id of the `Event` it created.

What's the correct syntax there? It's not as if `@user.event.id` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@user.events.last.id
```

When you have a `has_many`or `has_and_belongs_to_many` you are always dealing with a collection of associated models.

Comment: Will this not cause a problem if an event is added at some point between the insertion and this query? I'd have thought there was a reference to the event kept somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The controller would need to explicitly call event's user and be placed in the views that you want it displayed...as an example...i want to place it in **show** page for Events.

```
def show    
 @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end
```

View would be to get the id

```
<%= @event.user.id %>
```

Hope this helps...I believe this will help your problem. If not please advise